# Read ahead in an array to predict later outcomes in C

Tags: c, arrays, countdown, pic32

Basically what I'm trying to ask is, is there anyway to read ahead in an array so that you could create a 'case' for it.

For ex: you array has only integers such as: 0 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3

and what you want to try to do is create a coutdown till the next non zero number. Basically display the countdown. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please explain more! i dont understand...

Comment: Basically I want to display the countdown that it takes till the next non-zero number
being for the first case... until it hits the number '4' show the countdown from the first 0 to that 4 so 4,3,2,1 "actual number". Then, from that 4 till 1 is only 1 zero so: 1, "actual number", etc.

Comment: Well, are you allowed to read the array several times? What is the purpose of your program?

Comment: purpose of the program is to display a different text (relevant to the specified number). No text for 0. Basically to have it countdown till the next number in the array thats non-zero. But a certain condition has to be met when the non-zero is hit

Comment: So when 0 do nothing. When 4 (lets say):
   if (condition 1 meets array condition non-zero number)
       do this
    reset countdown and continue counting till next non-zero

Comment: Please update the question (rather than adding comments). Please show the expected output for the given input (it might be the printed sequence 4 1 12).  Reference to a mysterious 'certain condition' should either be demysticized or deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, };

    int a_size  = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < a_size)
    {
        if (array[i] == 0)
        {
            int j;
            for (j = i; j < a_size; j++)
                if (array[j] != 0)
                    break;
            printf("%d\n", j - i);
            i = j;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

produces this output:

```
4
1
12
```

If that's what you want, that's roughly what you need.  If it is not what you want, you need to explain more clearly what it is that you want.

---

Revised code for revised expected output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, };

    int a_size  = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < a_size)
    {
        if (array[i] == 0)
        {
            int j;
            for (j = i; j < a_size; j++)
                if (array[j] != 0)
                    break;
            int k = j - i;
            while (k > 0)
                printf(" %d", k--);
            i = j;
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" '");
            i++;
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Revised output:

```
 4 3 2 1 ' 1 ' 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 '
```

Comment: Ah, sort of. The 12 I imagine is total arr size (20) - 4 - 3 - 1 = 12. I'll try to explain it a bit better:

Couter:4 3 2 1 ' 1 ' 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 '

array: 0 0 0 0 4 0 1 0  0  0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3

Is there any way of representing that?

Comment: The 12 is the number of zeroes between the 1 and the 3 in the array (at least, that's how it is calculated). It is also the length (20) minus the lengths of the other two sets of zeroes, minus the number of non-zeroes.  Yes, please try to explain again what you want (edit the question — mainly adding information), and how you determine the answer, and the expected answer for the given data.