# Create an "array style" countdown in c

Tags: c, arrays, countdown, pic32

What I want to know is, if it's possible to create a countdown in c, BUT have a condition for when it hits an "unsual" piece of data in the array. I'll explain better with examples.

This is also similar to: [Read ahead in an array to predict later outcomes in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167106/read-ahead-in-an-array-to-predict-later-outcomes-in-ch)

however, it was poorly worded. So, I am rewording this question.

Ex: The array is an integer array with : `0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 2`

So, when its zero, don't do anything.
However, when it's non-zero, display the text associated with the number (according to some condition).

With pseudocode it'd be something like this:

```
if 0 dont do anything    ====>   within this countdown till next non-zero
if != 0 then display text asociated
reset countdown till next non-zero.
```

Is there any way this can be achieved? Basically, this would mean you could predict or read ahead in the array. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Please don't add the same question again. Instead, you can edit the original to add details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read ahead in an array to predict later outcomes in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167106/read-ahead-in-an-array-to-predict-later-outcomes-in-c)

Comment: However, it has been answered. Sorry about that.